# Launch view from app delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to launch a view from the delegate (and switch the selectedViewController).After the view switching I need to execute a view method from the delegate....How I can do that.
For mor precision this is the app delegate method.

```
-(void)launchOtherView{
NavigationCtrl *navCtrl = [self.rootController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];

    PrimaryView *prmView;

    //Need to lauch the view(navCtrl) .. for that it's ok..

    //Now I need to get the first view of the navCtrl...

    //After I need to execute a view method (someMethod:)
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Drop the navigation controller from the tools--->Library-->objects.

connect the navigation controller to its instance created in appdelegate class.

open MainWindow.xib and connect the file's owner delegate to instance of UINavigationController.

Drop the navigation controller object and inside atttach the view contoller which view you want to launch first.

All inside the implementation file of the will get executed.